Fundamental advantages of decomposing unitary representation into irreducible representations
I'm currently studying unitary representations and am particularly interested in the process of decomposing these representations into irreducible components, whether through direct sums or integrals. While I understand the theoretical basis of such decompositions, I feel a little bit unmotivated.
Most resources I searched online emphasize that decomposing representations into irreducibles is an interesting and nontrivial task, but they often stop short of illustrating the subsequent applications or benefits of doing so. Are the results of such decomposition useful mainly because one can more easily study certain other operators that respect the symmetry of the group being represented (like Laplacian on translation group $\mathbb{R}^n$)? References to literature or resources that delve into these applications would be highly appreciated.

A starting point for much signal analysis is to decompose a time-domain signal into a frequency-domain signal using a Fourier transform. The component frequencies are the irreducible components in the representation theory of (depending on the kind of Fourier transform you're interested in) of the additive group $(\mathbb{R}, +)$, or the circle group.
